# Xcode>Assets 1x 2x 3x fullscreen image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, jpeg

I am working on an Universal app with several UIImageViews in portrait mode (architectural photographs in jpg) with 0 constraints filling the whole scene. The photographs should be represented with a maximum of quality.

There are currently 10 different screen sizes (incl. iPads):

640px × 1136px, 
750px × 1334px, 
828px × 1792px, 
1125px × 2436px, 
1242px × 2208px, 
1242px × 2688px, 
1536px × 2048px, 
1668px × 2224px, 
1668px × 2388px, 
2048px × 2732px

but the image-well only caters for three inputs (1x, 2x, 3x).
What is the best compromise to solve '3 fits 10' problem without coding?
Obviously it has to be a compromise accepting re-rendering and stretching.
Any experiences what is best to do?
Something like 750x1334, 1536x2048, 2048x2732?

Comment: you can go for a single scale image in a .pdf format

Comment: ... so there is a difference, if I just scale the jpg or a jpg contained in a pdf ????

Comment: That mostly depends on what is on you image.

Comment: Can you expand on that? Is the algorithm different? I always had the believe that a pdf simply CONTAINS a  jpg and that the rendering algorithm are the same?

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer: PDF compression uses the same algorithm (DCTDecode) as jpg and the image is then drawn in the PDF contents stream. The difference is that a jpg compresses pixel, whereas pdf compresses binary data. ... At least that is how I understood it.